# Unexpected behavior of Variables

Tags: variable

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate. `Variables` has a strange behavior when it encounters powers:

```
  w = s1^(n + 2) s2;
  Variables[w]
  (*{s1, s1^n, s2}*)
```

I'd have expected `{s1, s2, n}`,

On the other hand

```
 w = s1^2 s2;
 Variables[w]
 (*{s1, s2}*)
```

yields what one expects. I wonder if there is a way to get the expected result in the first example.

Comment: Perhaps this is the issue: Under the Possible Issues section of the documentation for `Variables`, it says: "`Variables` looks for variables only inside sums, products, and rational powers". That indicates to me that since it can't assume that `n+2` is rational, it fails.

Comment: `Block[{n = 2}, Variables[w]]` gives the answer you are looking for (the `2` can be replaced with an arbitrary integer).  Does this suit your needs?

Comment: @march yes, thanks, that's the issue. I'm wondering if there is a way to fix this, i.e. to get the expected result.

Comment: @mikado well, this does not list `n`. Of course I can find out by hand what the variables are, but I'm wondering if Mathematica can do it for me.

Comment: The question is what is a variable. You could do `Union@Cases[w, _Symbol,Infinity]`, but if you also want to get an `f` from, say `f[n]`, then you might want to use `Union@Select[Cases[w, _Symbol, Infinity, Heads -> True], 
  Context[#] =!= "System`" &]'

Comment: @RolfMertig Thanks! `Union@Cases[w, _Symbol,Infinity]` is what I was looking for. If you post it I'll be happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: `Variables[Level[w, {-1}]]`

Answer (score 1):

That's because Variables[w] only show the independent variables inside sums, products, and rational powers, according to the documentation:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variables.html?q=Variables

So, even if you put `Variables[E^x]` the result will show `{}`. In you example, `s1^(n + 2) s2` is the same as `s1^n s1^2 s2` and the independet variables for that expression are s1, s1^n and s2.